# Depth of Field Effect in OGRE

Tags: 3d, ogre3d

Can anybody provide me with a quick code to implement depth of field effect in OGRE?

Comment: You might try google instead.

Answer (score 0):

This thread post contains several links to DOF source + demo 
http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=18074 ?

Comment: The link is now dead.